# apache2 error when restarting

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

im getting this error when restarting apache ,after i did a couple of a2ensite commands something when wrong and now it diesnt want to restart

```
    [Mon Sep 10 23:00:52 2012] [warn] pid file /var/run/apache2.pid overwritten 
-- Unclean shutdown of pre        vious Apache run?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try :

```
sudo rm /var/run/apache2.pid
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

?

Comment: just tried it now it just fails and doesnt give any error message

Answer (score 0):

did a reload `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` and everything ok now